# How to use stream value in second stream?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have try with 2 stream:

```
  Stream stream1() =>

... //return data from Firestore



  Stream stream2 {

    List listFromStream1;
    stream1().listen((event) {
      listFromStream1 = event.key;
    });
```

But problem is listFromStream1 = event.key; is call too late so listFromStream1 is null

How to solve?

Comment: Please provide your stream 1 content